# Change font in navigation bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uinavigationbar

I'd like to change the font in the navigation bar. However the following code doesn't work, it causes the app to crash.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Light.ttf", size: 34)!]

     return true
}
```

I am getting the following error:

fatal error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(lldb)`

I have indeed added the font **Lato-Light.ttf** to my project so it should be able to find it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`UIFont()` is a failable initalizer, it may fail due to several reasons. A forced unwrap using `!` crashes your app.

Better initialize it separately and check for success:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Light.ttf", size: 34) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
}
```

And check if your font file is included in the bundle resources.

[Common Mistakes With Adding Custom Fonts to Your iOS App](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Comment: I tried adding a println("Code executes") and it doesn't print to the console so clearly that part of the code doesn't execute. I am using the font in my app, so I know it's there. I wonder why it can't find the font?

Comment: Check the project target and see if it is included in the bundle resources.

Comment: How do I check if it's included? Sorry, I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: I have included a link in my answer.

Comment: I think I'm almost there. How do I run this code in Swift?

Comment: for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
        
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks. The error was due to the fact that I had to remove .ttf. Thanks!

Comment: I'd advise to create extension on UIFont and add fonts there. Analogical with colours etc -> easier to reconfigure later. Eg: extension `UIFont {
    class var navbarTitleFont: UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
    }`

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()

    }

    func configureView() {

        // Change the font and size of nav bar text
        if let navBarFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 20.0) {
            let navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
                NSFontAttributeName: navBarFont
            ]
            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
        }
    }

}
```